# Should I use was or were?

Tags: grammar

Should I use *was* or *were* in this line?

> The following informations about this item **was** contributed by Mr.X:
>   Item price, Item location.

Comment: "Following informations" (plural) should be corrected to "following information" (singular) because "information" is uncountable. Once the subject has been corrected, then the verb should be the singular form, "was".

Comment: @fjack: thanks for the answer. May I know what you mean by "information" is uncountable? I am showing two variables price and location. Isn't it countable?

Comment: @fjack Pls write an answer, if you would.

Comment: @QueenSarah: A good question. +1 for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use "was" here.
2. There is another correction for you. Since "information" is an uncountable noun, it has no plural form.
3. When you are using 'commas' with list of words, just use 'and' in between to separate the last two words. You can use 'commas' in  between to separate other words

Finally, see your sentence below after fixing grammar issues

**"The following information about this item was contributed by Mr.X: Item price and Item location."**

Please comment on this if you need more clarifications. 
Cheers!

Comment: Note that #3 is not a universally accepted rule.  Many people usually included a comma before the _and_ at the end of a list.  ("Oxford comma" or "Serial comma") Multiple websites provide humorous examples of misunderstandings that could arise due to omission of this punctuation.  https://www.google.com/#q=funny+oxford+comma